# Problem with putting tikzpicture to figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats

I have a problem with putting this plot to `figure` declaration. When I'm trying put this code to `figure`, I'm receiving this error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `Y' or `Y0' (in '0Y0.0e0]').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

I think that the error is caused by this line `nodes near coords style={at ={(\pgfplotspointmeta,\pgfplotspointy)},anchor=west}`, but I don't know how can I get around with it?

Code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                calc,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric
                }

\definecolor{11}{HTML}{685d5c}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4},
    axis y line*=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
        height=30cm,
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\footnotesize},
    xtick={0,10,...,70},
    width=100mm,
    bar width=3mm,
        ylabel=wiek,
        xlabel=\% respondentów,
    yticklabels={
            {>~55},
            {40~--~55},
            {30~--~39},
        {20~--~29},
            {<~20}
        },
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=70,
        ymax=4,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
    y=6mm,
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.75},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={at ={(\pgfplotspointmeta,\pgfplotspointy)},anchor=west},
    visualization depends on=y \as \pgfplotspointy,
    every axis plot/.append style={fill}
]
\addplot[11] coordinates
{(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (9,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[11] coordinates
{(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (61,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[11] coordinates
{(0,0) (0,1) (22,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[11] coordinates
{(0,0) (7,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[11] coordinates
{(1,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Generated plot without `figure`:

[image: plot]

Comment: Please provide a complete but minimal example. Your code should produce the error you quote when we compile it (and not, say, a complaint that `\usepackage` is undefined. It shouldn't include anything unnecessary to reproduce the error.  `subfigure` is obsolete and ought not be used. Your question suggests your code works if you don't put it in a `figure`. Does it?

Comment: Note that the complete error message includes a line number, which you've omitted.

Comment: Processed the code given and found no error. It produces the graph pictured.

Comment: The same. I have no error running your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I could successfully run your codes, one potential source of error can be the usage of `<` and `>` characters in text mode. You can simply avoid such problems by using them in math mode, i.e., `$<$` and `$>$`.

Here is your code after removing unnecessary packages and using the single guillemets in math mode:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{11}{HTML}{685d5c}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4},
    axis y line*=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
        height=30cm,
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\footnotesize},
    xtick={0,10,...,70},
    width=100mm,
    bar width=3mm,
        ylabel=wiek,
        xlabel=\% respondentów,
    yticklabels={
            {$>$~55},
            {40~--~55},
            {30~--~39},
        {20~--~29},
            {$<$~20}
        },
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=70,
        ymax=4,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
    y=6mm,
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.75},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={at ={(\pgfplotspointmeta,\pgfplotspointy)},anchor=west},
    visualization depends on=y \as \pgfplotspointy,
    every axis plot/.append style={fill}
]
\addplot[11] coordinates
{(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (9,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[11] coordinates
{(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (61,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[11] coordinates
{(0,0) (0,1) (22,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[11] coordinates
{(0,0) (7,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\addplot[11] coordinates
{(1,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sina it was exactly this. However when I've removed indicated line by me, then the bar plot are produced but with errors. Anyway, your solution works! :)